# How to extract a List which is inside the bundle and show the content in the next activity?

Tags: android

I put an ArrayList object into a bundle of my activity. Now in the next view I want to fill the content of these list elements into my view. How can I write something into my Edittext field in the `onCreate` method?

```
EditText comment;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comment_picture);

    if (savedInstanceState != null){

        ArrayList<String> selectedPics = (ArrayList<String>) savedInstanceState.get("pics");                        
    }       
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found your **EditText** you can with method [findViewById()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29), like this

```
comment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ID_THAT_YOU_SET_IN_XML_FILE_FOR_THAT_WIDGET);
```

If you want add all items of **selectedPics** in one string, you can use thatcode:

```
final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String item: selectedPics) {
    builder.append(item);
}
comment.setText(builder.toString());
```

Or, if you need set items in different lines and your EditText is multiline, use that code:

```
final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String item: selectedPics) {
    builder.append(item).append("\n");
}
comment.setText(builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

res > layout > activity_comment_picture

```
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myEditTextID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

---

```
    comment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditTextID); // initializing EditText through id set in xml layout
    String myTextfromList="";
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedPics.size(); i++) {
        myTextfromList += selectedPics.get(i);              
    }           

    comment.setText(myTextfromList);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: its not the problem how to extract the complete text from the list, my problem is that comment is null an I do not now how do I get it in the oncreate method

Comment: you get it this way: comment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditTextID); , see the updated answer!

Comment: got it now?? or still a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I described my problem wrong. The problem for me is, that I do not know how to get the comment widget in the oncreate method.

```
EditText comment;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comment_picture);

    if (savedInstanceState != null){

        ArrayList<String> selectedPics = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("pics");

       //HOW TO RETRIEVE THE comment Widget


    }



}
```